# Trying to find ratio of current value to previous in R

Tags: r

I am taking an excel file as input and want to find display the ratio of previous value to current value of each row.

Example

Input column from excel

```
 1. Input   Output
 2. 50      2
 3. 25      2.5
 4. 10      0.5
 5. 20
```

What function can I use to do this?

Comment: Try `lag` i.e. `dat %>% mutate(Output = lag(Input)/Input)`.  How did you get `0.5` for the first row

Comment: @akrun thanks! and my bad it should be 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(Output = lead(lag(Input)/Input))
```

-output

```
  Input Output
1    50    2.0
2    25    2.5
3    10    0.5
4    20     NA
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Input = c(50, 25, 10, 20)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```